# JavaScript/HTML hover menu/toolbar

Tags: javascript, user-interface

Don't really know how to formulate the question. A picture is worth a thousand words:

[JavaScript Hover Toolbar http://queenbee.alponline.ru/hover.jpg](http://queenbee.alponline.ru/hover.jpg)

Here, cursor hovers over "Home" item, and the toolbar to the left pops up.

Is there a standard way to do this? Preferably with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with CSS, no javascript needed
or with one of the [menu plugins from jquery](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Plugins/category/44)