# a hideable and 'recyclable' javascript context toolbar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am searching for plugins/scripts that provide a toolbar when hovering elements of a big list. Almost like in this question:
[JavaScript/HTML hover menu/toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139406/javascript-html-hover-menu-toolbar)

However, I don't want it to be a css-menu-like one. As I said, It will be a very big list and I would like its markup not to be duplicated *n* times. So I need a javascript that will move the same toolbar from list element to list element when they're hovered.

I know the [YUI2 tooltip](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/container/tooltip/) applies this strategy of moving the tooltip element, and changing the contents at display, but it's only for informative text displaying. I can't add buttons to it, and it's positionned according to the actual mouse position, and not to the element hovered.

ps: I tagged this question jQuery because the project is using it but i'm open to any framework-dependant or not solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var toolbar = $('#toolbar');
$('#yourTable').delegate('.has-tooltip', 'mouseenter', function() {
    toolbar.insertBefore(this);
}).delegate('.has-tooltip', 'mouseleave', function() {
    toolbar.detach();
});
```

The delegate will trigger for those events on elements matching `.has-tooltip` which are inside `#yourTable`.

Comment: Thanks for this proposal. As I said, it's intended to be implement on big lists ( say 300~4000 items ), and this script will instanciate as many listeners. Can some delegation be done with hover ? I know of live() but if thinks it listens to the whole document when I only need to listen to a container.

Comment: It will instantiate many listeners but only a single toolbar. I'll update the answer to use a delegate.